# Moving multiple files from one folder to another and rename them

Tags: shell-script

I have a list of current file names and Original file names in a text file.  The current name and the original name are seperated by a Tab or hypen.

I want to move the file with the current file name from one directory to another directory and rename the file in the destination directory.  How can I do this with the shell script.

Comment: Please post a sample of the text file and clarify the difference between "current" and "original" file names and what the final directory structure should look like: at the moment is it not clear at all as to what you are asking.

Comment: @Vaish [Using text list to batch-rename files](http://askubuntu.com/q/318611/283843) On AU.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the exact format of your text file containing the filenames. The simplest form would be something like this, if the textfile contains the absolute path and filename:

```
xargs -a textfile -n 2 mv
```